# Check response time on sent message - possible with using only SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to figure out the general response time per. message. So, every time SENDER sends a message to RECEIVER, what how many seconds (think converting to UNIX timestamp would be the suitable solution, and then dividing) went, before the user responded.

I have this table:

```
+--------------+----------+
|    Field     |   Type   |
+--------------+----------+
| msg_id       | int(11)  |
| msg_sender   | int(11)  |
| msg_receiver | int(11)  |
| msg_date     | datetime |
| msg_message  | longtext |
+--------------+----------+
```

I have tried for about an hour to figure out how to even put this up, and all my solutions are horrible long, complicated and/or inefficient, and this made me wonder, if it even possible/most efficient to do it via MySQL.

Maybe some of you could point me in the right direction.

Comment: What if the first user sends 2 messages with 1 response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select t1.*, min(t2.msg_date) as response_date 
from mytable t1 join mytable t2 
      on t1.msg_sender=t2.msg_receiver and t2.msg_sender=t1.msg_receiver and t2.msg_date>t1.msg_date
group by t1.msg_sender,t1.msg_receiver,t1.msg_date
```

For each message in t1 we get corresponding answers sent after t1 message and group them to get minimal response date (first answer date).

Place the select above in a subquery and find AVG of response_date - msg_date

UPDATE
You used incorrect table m2.*  I replaced with m1.* and results are there

```
SELECT
    AVG(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(response_date) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(msg_date)),
    AVG(response_date - msg_date)
FROM
(SELECT
    m1.*,
    min(m2.msg_date) as response_date 
FROM
    edu_messages m1
JOIN
    edu_messages m2 ON m1.msg_sender = m2.msg_receiver AND m2.msg_sender = m1.msg_receiver AND m2.msg_date > m1.msg_date 
GROUP BY
    m1.msg_sender,
    m1.msg_receiver,
    m1.msg_date) AS table1
```

Comment: Nice - like that way of doing it. Responses on the AVG is 0 though. I have created a SQL fiddle for you to see: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6d370/1

Comment: Nice. That is pretty cool. I will work around with it - thank you very much. You're a genius.