# MySQL count Total Logged In Time for Application

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to count total Logged In time for every user for my application.

I am providing necessary DDL and DML queries for necessary test data [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/61bb7/1).

I tried this Query for resolving my purpose.

```
select userId,
sum(loginTimeInHour) as loginTimeInHour
from(
    select e1.userId, (TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(IFNULL(e2.time,NOW()),e1.time)))/(60*60) as loginTimeInHour from 
    EventLog e1
    left join EventLog e2
    on e1.userId = e2.userId
    and e2.eventType = 'LOGOUT'
    and e1.time < e2.time
    where e1.eventType = 'LOGIN'
    group by e1.id having min(IFNULL(e2.time,NOW()) - e1.time)
) temp
group by userId;
```

Here I am getting wrong result in one scenario. Suppose any user1 **login at time t1**, then suppose any how **System didn't able to capture logout** event for user1. And after that user1 **login again at time t2** in the System and **logout at time t3**. So I have to ignore that first event of login which happened at time t1. My Query can't do this. My Query returns me **(t3-t2)+(t3-t1).** My expected result for this scenario is **(t3-t2).**  Any help? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296650/check-response-time-on-sent-message-possible-with-using-only-sql/22297081#22297081 see the example. In your case it would be almost the same

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just find all login/logout without an event between them, and sum the intervals;

```
SELECT e1.userid, SUM(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(COALESCE(e2.time, NOW())) - 
                      UNIX_TIMESTAMP(e1.time))/3600 total 
FROM eventlog e1 
LEFT JOIN eventlog e2
  ON e1.userid = e2.userid AND e2.eventType='LOGOUT' AND e1.time < e2.time
LEFT JOIN eventlog e3
  ON e1.userid = e3.userid AND e1.time < e3.time AND e3.time < e2.time
WHERE e1.eventType='LOGIN' AND e3.time IS NULL
GROUP BY e1.userid
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/54c84/1).

Note that this (as your original query) does not take time zones into account. The best way to solve that problem is probably to save all times in UTC and use UTC_TIMESTAMP() instead of NOW() for the query.

Comment: Yes @Joachim Isaksson you are right. Don't consider timezone in that. I already used UTC_TIMESTAMP in my original development query. Thanks

Comment: It's give me right results but can you please help me to understand logic behind that? :(

Comment: @VishalZanzrukia Basically it selects all rows with `LOGIN` (e1) and LEFT JOINs to find a following `LOGOUT` (e2). If there is none (ie the logout time is NULL), it uses `COALESCE` to use `NOW()` as logout time instead. "After" doing that, it checks if there is an event between the two (e3), and in that case throws them away. That will throw away the first login in case of `LOGIN/LOGIN/LOGOUT` since there is an event between it and the logout.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson: Wow, that's a great solution. So simple and so complete. Just great.

Comment: Hi @JoachimIsaksson, suppose if I want to throw away `LOGIN/LOGIN` entry as well, then?  Please help me if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You need to check for two conditions.  You only want adjacent pairs of login/logout.  One way to do this is to find the next logout record.  Then, count the number of login records between them.  Only choose the number that have no other login records.

I prefer to do "next" type calculations using correlated subqueries, rather than non-equijoins and aggregation.  Here is how I would write this query:

```
select userid, 
       sum(TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(coalesce(el.nextLogoutTime, now()), time))/(60*60)) as loginTimeInHour
from (select el.*,
             (select count(*)
              from EventLog el2
              where el2.userId = el.userId and
                    el2.eventType = 'LOGIN' and
                    el2.time < el.nextLogoutTime and
                    el2.time > el.time
             ) as NumLogIns
      from (select el.*,
                   (select max(time)
                    from EventLog el2
                    where el2.userId = el.userId and
                          el2.eventType = 'LOGOUT' and
                          el2.time > el.time
                   ) as nextLogoutTime
            from EventLog el
            where el.eventType = 'LOGIN'
           ) el
     ) el
where NumLogins = 0
group by el.userid;
```

Comment: Hi.. @Gordon, can you please refer this link? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/144a10/1 Its giving me wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

For every login

1. find the next logout (later logout with minimum distance)
2. find the next login (later login with minimum distance)
3. if next login is before next logout, then ignore the login record

Here is the statement. I hope it works:

```
select 
  userId,
  sum(logintimeinhour) as totallogintimeinhour
from
(
  select 
    login.userid, 
    min(time_to_sec(timediff(ifnull(later_logout.time,now()), login.time)))/(60*60) as loginTimeInHour
  from EventLog login
  left join EventLog later_login 
    on later_login.eventType = 'LOGIN' 
    and later_login.userId = login.userId
    and later_login.time > later_login.time
  left join EventLog later_logout 
    on later_logout.eventType = 'LOGOUT' 
    and later_logout.userId = login.userId
    and later_logout.time > later_login.time
  where login.eventType = 'LOGIN'
  group by login.id
  having
    min( ifnull(later_logout.time,now()) ) <=
    min( ifnull(later_login.time,now()) )
)
group by userid
order by userid;
```