# SQL Check response time on sent message

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to figure out the general response time per. message. So, every time SENDER sends a message to RECEIVER, what how many seconds went, before RECEIVER responded.

I have this table with messages:

```
+------------------+----------+
|    Field         |   Type   |
+------------------+----------+
| id               | int      |
| at_date          | datetime |
| out              | bool     |  # outcoming message if true, incoming if false
\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\\
```

I already tried this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22297081/12324707

But there is one problem. Sender can send two and more messages.

My current colution:

```
SELECT avg(responses.resp_time - responses.at_date)  AS avg_1
FROM (SELECT message_metrics_1.at_date      AS at_date,
             min(message_metrics_2.at_date) AS resp_time
      FROM message_metrics AS message_metrics_1
               JOIN message_metrics AS message_metrics_2
                    ON message_metrics_2.at_date >
                       message_metrics_1.at_date AND message_metrics_2.out AND
                       NOT message_metrics_1.out
      GROUP BY message_metrics_1.at_date) AS responses
```

Maybe I need to separate messages to "blocks" by `out` field.

**Problem demo of subquery**

Data:

```
date                       | out
---------------------------+-----
2019-11-05 07:07:58.000000 | false # ignore
2019-11-05 07:10:20.000000 | false # ignore
2019-11-05 07:10:27.000000 | false # ask
2019-11-05 07:10:36.000000 | true  # response
2019-11-05 06:05:13.000000 | false # ask
2019-11-05 06:05:42.000000 | true  # response
```

Result:

```
at_date ( ask )            | resp_time (response)
---------------------------+---------------------------
2019-11-05 06:05:13.000000 | 2019-11-05 06:05:42.000000
2019-11-05 07:07:58.000000 | 2019-11-05 07:10:36.000000
2019-11-05 07:10:20.000000 | 2019-11-05 07:10:36.000000
2019-11-05 07:10:27.000000 | 2019-11-05 07:10:36.000000
```

Want to:

```
at_date ( ask )            | resp_time (response)
---------------------------+---------------------------
2019-11-05 07:10:27.000000 | 2019-11-05 07:10:36.000000
2019-11-05 06:05:13.000000 | 2019-11-05 06:05:42.000000
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/paMQ99guouudPuAYtZPVyL/1

Comment: How to identify which one to ignore? Is that so the we should consider only if `true` (reponse) comes after `false` (ask)

Comment: Last possible response/ask. I have possible solution, it looks good, but I can't test it now(for ~9 hours): https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=42d90a33685ef7e93d4bfd113d45ccb0

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, you want the first `out = false` followed by the time of the next `out = true`.

One method uses a cumulative filtered `min()`:

```
select *
from (select mm.*,
             min(at_date) filter (where out) over (order by at_date desc) as next_out,
             lag(out) over (order by at_date) as prev_out
      from message_metrics mm
     ) mm
where not out and (prev_out is null or prev_out)
order by at_date;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=b4f460591f17e3373e06f2c25c2d77d9) is a db<>fiddle.